# How to disable logout on timeout with Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, session-timeout, rpxnow

I'm running a Rails web app where the authentication system is based on Authlogic and tardate's [authlogic_rpx](http://github.com/tardate/authlogic_rpx).

The first one handles everything about sessions, the second one does the mapping with RPX/Janrain (which offers the users to sign in with Twitter or Facebook).

All the users are always automatically logged out after a certain inactivity time (I never managed to know how long), though I disabled the automatic logout and even set up the logout time to 1.year as explained in [Authlogic documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/Timeout).

What should I do to keep my users logged in?

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it. It's written in the documentation that the remember_me parameter will do it:

`UserSession.create(:login => "bjohnson", :password => "my password", :remember_me => true)`

Unfortunately, it's [not working](http://binarylogic.lighthouseapp.com/projects/18752/tickets/138-remember_me-option-not-saving-with-usersessionnew), so I had to add this line below:

`UserSession.remember_me = true`

…and the magic cookie is finally created!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place the line (`UserSession.remember_me = true`)?

In the create action of the user_sessions_controller?

Or in the User model?